# Adding to values in a dictionary from two lists of different length

Tags: python, list

I have four lists that look like this:

```
lista = [['l', 'k'],['e', '3'],['c', 'k'],['x', 'i'],['d', 'f']]
listanum = [1,2,3,4,5]
listb = [['a', 'k'],['c', 'm'],['v', 'f']]
listbnum = [1,3,4]
```

`lista` and `listanum` are synchronized, `listb` and `listbnum` too.
I want to make a dictionary where the keys are the items in `listanum` and the values are items in `lista` and `listb`, the outcome would be:

```
di = {1: [['l','k'],['a', 'k']], 
      2: [['e', '3'],[]], 
      3:[['c','k'],['c', 'm']], 
      4: [['x', 'i'],['v', 'f']], 
      5: [['d', 'f'][]]
}
```

so if there is no value for a number in listanum in listb, the second list in the dictionarys values is empty.

I have tried this:

```
di = {}
for i in xrange(len(lista)):
  pos = listanum[i]
  if pos not in di:
    di[pos] = [[],[]]
  di[pos][0].append(lista[i])  
  if i in listbnum:
    di[pos][1].append(listb[i])
```

but get this error message: `'IndexError: list index out of range'`. I cant see why it is out of range???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zip the items, and use `collections.defaultdict` to default the values to `list`s:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

di = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in chain(zip(listanum, lista), zip(listbnum, listb)):
    di[key].append(value)
```

I used `chain` to make looping over both sets of key-value pairs easier; this works in both Python 2 and 3. If this is Python 2 only code, you could use `+` to concatenate the two lists.

Output with `pprint` and converting back to a regular `dict` to make printing easier:

```
>>> pprint(dict(di))
{1: [['l', 'k'], ['a', 'k']],
 2: [['e', '3']],
 3: [['c', 'k'], ['c', 'm']],
 4: [['x', 'i'], ['v', 'f']],
 5: [['d', 'f']]}
```

This does not create empty lists for the second set; if you *have* to have empty lists, you are limited to building two separate dictionaries then merging those:

```
dicta = dict(zip(listanum, lista))
dictb = dict(zip(listbnum, listb))

di = {k: [dicta.get(k, []), dictb.get(k, [])] for k in dicta.viewkeys() | dictb.viewkeys()}
```

for Python 2, for Python 3 use `.keys()` instead of `.viewkeys()`, to produce:

```
>>> pprint(di)
{1: [['l', 'k'], ['a', 'k']],
 2: [['e', '3'], []],
 3: [['c', 'k'], ['c', 'm']],
 4: [['x', 'i'], ['v', 'f']],
 5: [['d', 'f'], []]}
```

Specifically, for your code, you confused `i` (the index into `lista`) with `pos`:

```
  if i in listbnum:
    di[pos][1].append(listb[i])
```

For `i = 4`, `i in listbnum` is `True`, but `listb[4]` does not exist. Your code also tried to *append* the lists from `lista` and `listb`, which would not result in the correct output.

Altering your version a little to work, using a *separate* loop for the `listb`/`listbnum` lists:

```
di = {}
for i, pos in enumerate(listanum):
    if pos not in di:
        di[pos] = [[],[]]
    di[pos][0][:] = lista[i]

for i, pos in enumerate(listbnum):
    di[pos][1][:] = listb[i]
```

Comment: would not a `+` sufficed instead of a chain ? (in this case)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Not if this is Python 3.

Comment: What was wrong with my code? why is it out of range? Is the problem not easily solved with a modified version of my code instaed of using functions from chain and defaultdict?

Answer (score 5):

```
In [7]: da = dict(zip(listanum, lista))

In [8]: db = dict(zip(listbnum, listb))

In [9]: {k:[da.get(k,[]), db.get(k,[])] for k in set(listanum + listbnum)}
Out[9]: 
{1: [['l', 'k'], ['a', 'k']],
 2: [['e', '3'], []],
 3: [['c', 'k'], ['c', 'm']],
 4: [['x', 'i'], ['v', 'f']],
 5: [['d', 'f'], []]}
```

Comment: +1, but I'd go with  repalcing `set(listanum + listbnum)` with `da.keys() | db.keys()` (or, in 2.7, `da.viewkeys() | db.viewkeys()`).

Comment: @Lattyware: Thanks for the suggestion. My argument for the version in my answer is that it's portable across 2.7 and 3.x.

Comment: True, although 2to3 should happily convert `dict.viewkeys()` to `dict.keys()`. It's definitely not a big deal though, both are pretty readable.

Comment: What was wrong with my code? why is it out of range? How can I code this with out the zip function and not in one line (so the logic is clearer)?